# Odoo 13 bugs in add section field and note after installing the app

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo-13

I am creating a customize module for Odoo 13 that inherits the sales order on the order line page.

This is my model

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields


class application(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    application = fields.Char()
```

This is my view.xml

```
<odoo>
    <record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Application</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
                <field name="application" string="Application"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <template id="application_document" inherit_id="sale.sale_order_portal_content">
        <xpath expr="//div[2]/section[1]/table//th[1]" position="before">
            <th class="text-left">Application</th>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//div[2]/section[1]/table//td[1]" position="before">
            <td>
                <span t-field="line.application"/>
            </td>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

This is my manifest.py

```
{
'name': "Application",

'summary': """
    Add a new field in sale order line - Application
    """,

'description': """
    This new field will determine the application of the said products in quotation
""",

'author': "Developer",
'website': "None",

# Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
# Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/addons/base/data/ir_module_category_data.xml
# for the full list
'category': 'Sales',
'version': '13.0.1.0.0',

# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['base', 'sale'],

# always loaded
'data': [
    # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'views/application.xml',
],
# only loaded in demonstration mode
'demo': [
    'demo/demo.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'application': True,
    'auto_install': False
}
```

The problem is that, after I installed the cust app, under the product where "add a section" and "add a note" won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your model to **_inherit = 'sale.order.line'**.You are trying to add the field in wrong object.

Thanks

Comment: When I tried to do that the "add a section" and "add a note" won't work